# Objects turning black when colliding when in render mode in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm having trouble on the latest released blender version (3.1.2) and whenever two objects collide or overlap the overlapping part turns black and it's really frustrating. this is only clearly seen in rendered mode. I've tried to look at the settings and preferences, but I can't find anything to fix it. It wasn't in the previous version as I just downloaded the new one.[image: This is two objects colliding in] [image: This is the two objects colliding in rendered mode]

Answer (score 1):

This is called Z fighting, overlapping faces will be rendered black in Cycles. You need to slightly scale or move one of you cube for example.